# FeathersJs: context.params.user returning undefined in before hook

Tags: javascript, express, feathersjs, feathers-authentication, feathers-hook

I'm getting undefined when I try to assign `user._id` to an entity in a before hook.

The hook

```
module.exports = (options = {}) => { 
return async context => { 

const user = context.params.user;

context.data = {
...
      userId: user._id,
...
    };
return context; 
}; 
};
```

This is my hooks register

```
  before: {
...
    create: [processProperty(), authenticate('jwt')],
...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by bringing the `authenticate` hook before my `processProperty` hook as shown below.
I think this is because each hook in the array is processed from left to right, so in this case, the `processProperty` hook needs access to the authenticated user, so it needs to come after the `authenticate` hook has been processed.

```
  before: {
...
    create: [authenticate('jwt'), processProperty()],
...
  }
}
```